# How to decrease socket.io room size

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket io for my chat application one to one. I am facing the issue right now. When user will disconnect or end chat manually by click the end chat button. But from socket that user not remove. Each time room size remains same. How can i remove that user from socket connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 socket.on('create or join', function(room)
    {
        numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length;
        console.log("user joining the room");
        console.log(numClients);

        if (numClients === 0)
        {
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('created', room);
        }
        else if (numClients == 1)
        {
            io.sockets. in (room).emit('join', room);
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('joined', room);
        }
        else
        {
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
        socket.emit('emit(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
        socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the socket.leave method.

"To leave a channel you call leave in the same fashion as join."

```
socket.leave('room');
```

Comment: I know but after doing this when I check the room size its remain same. I am checking room size using this io.sockets.clients(room).length

Comment: Can you share you relevant code here for me to debug?